# How to do unit testing of function which is depends on another function using karma jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to test getTokenExpirationDate() method which uses other method jwt_decode and it is imported from jwt-decode. How I can do unit testing for this method?. How This jwt_decode method can be mocked.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, Router} from '@angular/router';
import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem(('loginToken'));
    if (this.isTokenExpired(token)) {
      localStorage.removeItem('loginToken');
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  isTokenExpired(token: string): boolean {
    if (!token) { return true;
    } else {
      const date = this.getTokenExpirationDate(token);
      if (date === undefined) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return !(date.valueOf() > new Date().valueOf());
      }
    }
  }

  getTokenExpirationDate(token: string): Date {
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    if (decoded.exp === undefined) {
      return null;
    } else {
      const date = new Date(0);
      date.setUTCSeconds(decoded.exp);
      return date;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't try to mock it. I would simply pass a valid jwt token, that the function can decode.

Comment: Also regarding to your updated queston: I rather avoid calling `new Date().valueOf()` inside your methods. As its value will change depending on your local time. Rahter, inject a current time either in the constructor or in the method as a `now` value. Then you can create test cases that always behave the same. (You must have at some point glue code on where you are actually injecting the current time, but that should only be a starter script. In the tests, you can use mocked times.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mock `jwt_decode`. You only write test for `getTokenExpirationDate`.

`jwt_decode` is an internal call of your public function. You test it implicitly by writing test cases for `getTokenExpirationDate`.

It appears to be a pure function without sideeffects that you can safely use and your behavior of your method will remain consistent.

Use it, don't mock it or write unit tests for it. Test your business logic, not your dependencies.

---

And `jwt_decode` already has unit tests: https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/master/test/tests.js